# for loop skipping the content and showing further data

Tags: xslt

i have the below xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</meta>]]></xsl:text>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Per\NEW.css" type="text/css"></link>
      </head>
      <body>
        <section class="tr_chapter">
          <div class="chapter">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </div>
        </section>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="case">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="case.head"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="case.head">
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Plaintiff']"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">V</xsl:text>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Defendant']"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="case.ref.no.group | judge.line"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <div class="para">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="case.ref.no.group">
    <div class="section-sect3">
      <span class="font-style-bold">Court of Appeal</span>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="case.ref.no[1]/prefix" />
      <xsl:text> Nos. </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="case.ref.no">
        <xsl:value-of select="number" />
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="year" />
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = 2)">
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="judge.line">
    <div class="section-sect3">
      <xsl:for-each select="judge">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text> JC</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::date.group"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="date.group">
    <div class="section-sect4">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./date.line/date"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//catchwords.group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="catchwords.group">
    <div class="y">
      <xsl:for-each select="catchwords/catchword">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@level=1"><br/>
            <span class="font-style-bolditalic">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">-</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
              <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
              <xsl:if test="not(position() = last()-1)">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> – </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//headnotes"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="headnotes/para">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=1">
        <div class="x">
          <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="m">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="para.group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para.group">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::label)]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//counsel.group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="list">
    <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="list.item/label"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="list.item/label">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="para">
        <span class="item-num">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::case.considered">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::list.item"/>
      </div>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list.item">
    <xsl:variable name="a">
      <xsl:value-of select="./label"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="./label">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label|case.ref)]"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="counsel.group" name="j">
<div class="ital">
    <xsl:for-each select="./counsel.line">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">Judgment received: December 4, 2008</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ref.group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ref.group/leg.mentioned">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:text>Legislation mentioned in the judgment</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ref">
    <div class="nomar">
<xsl:value-of select="./@country"/>    
    </div>
      <div class="para">

        <xsl:value-of select="./citetitle"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ptr.group/leg.ptr">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <div class="section-sect1">
    <xsl:text>Cases cited in the judgment</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//case.considered"/>
     <div class="section-sec1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//other.mentioned"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="case.considered">
<xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:if test="./case.ref">
      <div class="para">
        <span class="font-style-italic">

            <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref/citetitle[@full]"/></span>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>        
    <xsl:value-of select="./case.ref/citecitation/@full"/>


        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="other.mentioned/other.ref">
<div class="para">
<xsl:value-of select="./author"/>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<span class="font-style-italic">
<xsl:value-of select="./book.title"/>
</span>
<xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="ed_vol"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./ref_grp/reference/pageno"/>
</div>
<xsl:apply-templates select="//judgment"/>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="judgment">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:value-of select="./judge.block/heading"/>
    </div>
    <!--<xsl:for-each select="./judge.block/para.group">
      --><!--<div class="para">
        <span class="new">
          <xsl:value-of select="./label"></xsl:value-of>
        </span>
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
      </div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./list"/>--><!--
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:for-each>-->
<xsl:apply-templates select="./judge.block/para.group"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="judge.block/para.group">

<div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./heading"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./para">
    <div class="para">
<span class="new">
    <xsl:value-of select="./label"/></span>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="./text()"/>
        </div>


        <xsl:if test="./block.quote">
        <xsl:for-each select="./block.quote/para.group">
        <div class="ali-itl">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:for-each select="./para.group">
        <div class="ali-itl">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>
        <div class="extract">
        <div class="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./para"/>
        </div></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="./para.group">
<xsl:if test="./para.group">

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(./para)">
        <div class="ital">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./heading"/>
        </div></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="ali-itl">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>

        <div class="para">
            <span class="new">
            <xsl:value-of select="./para/label"/>
        </span>

            <xsl:value-of select="./para/text()"/>
        </div>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>






        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:if test="./block.quote">
        <xsl:for-each select="./block.quote/para.group">
        <div class="ali-itl">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:for-each select="./para.group">
        <div class="ali-itl">
            <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
        </div>
        <div class="extract">
        <div class="para">
        <div class="new">
        <xsl:value-of select="./para/label"/>
        </div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="./para/text()"/>
        </div></div>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>



</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="emphasis">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="citetitle">
        <span class="font-style-italic">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./list.item"/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="./@type">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@type)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and when i use it on my xml, the output is skipping the content in between(for example i am able to see content with number[12] and then it is directly jumping to content in number [16] and the content in between is skipped). the xml can be found in the following link.
[XML Doc](http://pastebin.com/yFfY9tz4). please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure before I start trying this: Can your XSLT be minimized somehow so only your particular problem and exactly your particular problem gets apparent? Along the same vein, can you reduce your Xml document so is just long enough to show the problem and so it can be included in your question?

Comment: Hi @O.R.Mapper, thanks for the reply, i am sorry to say that i can't reduce either my XML or XSLT, as the xml is not in a flow. the output is generated by the flow going up and down. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really hard to tell from the information you gave, but I think your problem comes from the fact that the "para" elements with the "labels" 13-15 actually lie within a nested *second* para.group element within the first one.
Your template probably only matches "para" elements directly within "para.group" elements, but not nested "para.group" elements.

As an outsider, it's basically impossible to tell without investing way too much time in analyzing the huge input you gave, which is probably why you didn't receive another answer up until now.